# Как реализовать super().__init__() с аргументами от разных классов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

я хочу чтобы при создании экземпляра d класса Doktor вначале вызывался метод init от класса Person потом init класса  Driver и добавлялся ещё атрибут age от самого Doktor. Возможно ли такое сделать с помощью super() ???

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

class Draver:
    def __init__(self,car):
        self.car=car

class Doktor(Person,Draver):
    def __init__(self, name, surname,car, age):
        super().__init__(name, surname,car)
        self.age = age

p = Person("Jon", "smit")
d = Doktor("ivan", "ivanov","bibika", 30)
```

Comment: в строке super().__init__(name, surname,car) Pyton не понимает что аргумент car от класса Draver а не от Person как сделать так чтоб понял ?

Comment: и правильно "driver", а не "draver".

Answer (score 0):

Явный вызов конструкторов:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

class Draver:
    def __init__(self,car):
        self.car=car

class Doktor(Person,Draver):
    def __init__(self, name, surname,car, age):
        Person.__init__(self, name, surname)
        Draver.__init__(self, car)
        self.age = age

p = Person("Jon", "smit")
d = Doktor("ivan", "ivanov","bibika", 30)
print(d.name, d.surname, d.car, d.age)
# ivan ivanov bibika 30
```

Comment: Я понимаю что так можно Person.__init__(self, name, surname)
        Draver.__init__(self, car)  . Но можно ли такой же результат получить используя функцию super(). У меня больше академический интерес ,чем практический .

Comment: @Вячеслав, нашел вариант через именованный параметры в конструкторе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34885285/5909792 А так, по-моему, super вызывается для первого же типа-родителя, в вашем случае это Person. Мультинаследование не рекомендуется делать, вместо него используется включение объектов в поля